# smelling something Dangerous about update

Tags: updates, do-release-upgrade

I am attaching two screen shots, self explained. Why do an update asking something regarding my boot sector? isn't dangerous?

[image]

[image]

Comment: And that screenshot isn't asking anything about your boot sector.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the images there seems to be very less space in /boot.
You should remove your old and unused kernels following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels)

try this

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

to purge manually installed kernels

```
sudo purge-old-kernels
```

Comment: You need install `bikeshed` to get `purge-old-kernels`.